# I am updating state without mutating it, still I am not getting old state value in next renders of component

Tags: reactjs, state

I am very new to react and trying to learn basic things. While writing some test programs, I ran into a problem:
Basically I wanted to add new object to array after every 2 seconds and I am doing it with the help of useEffect and setInterval.
I followed the rule of react to not to mutate the state variable, so I created a new variable from old state and set that variable to state setter function. Still I found, it was not giving me updated state.

```
const [liveChats, setLiveChats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const newLiveChats = [...liveChats];
      newLiveChats.push({
        name: generateRandomName(),
        message: generateRandomMessage(20),
      });
      setLiveChats(newLiveChats);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

I managed to get the updated state with state updater function (as shown below), but I would like to understand what was wrong with old code. What's the rule of thumb here.

```
const [liveChats, setLiveChats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setLiveChats((prevState) => [
        {
          name: generateRandomName(),
          message: generateRandomMessage(20),
        },
        ...prevState,
      ]);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `useEffect` dependency array determines when it will re-run.

In your first snippet, your dependency array is empty, which means `liveChats` will only ever been the initial value of `liveChats`, which is an empty array.

So even if you push a new object to `newLiveChats` and update `liveChats`, on the next interval `liveChats` will not persist the newly pushed object.

Your second snippet works successfully because the functional update of `useState` lets you pass a function that receives the previous state as an argument, which ensures you're always adding onto the latest version of `liveChats`.

For illustration, you could modify your first code snippet like so:

```
const [liveChats, setLiveChats] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setLiveChats([
        ...liveChats,
        {
            name: generateRandomName(),
            message: generateRandomMessage(),
        }
    ]);
  }, 2000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [liveChats]); // Now it will re-run every time liveChats updates
```

In this example, I've added `liveChats` to the `useEffect` dependency array, so it will re-trigger it every time `liveChats` updates.

As a result, `liveChats` in the interval function will be the latest value.

Without the interval, however, this would be a bad practice because it would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @RyanChiang.. That make sense now. I was in impression that the callback function of interval will always point to updated value of liveChats in memory, but on the other hand as useEffect was only triggered on first render of component, the callback function formed closure with first ever liveChats in memory not later versions of it.